# Issue with callback url scheme for Paytm app

Tags: ios, swift, url-scheme, paytm

I have two applications- app1 and app2. App1 and App2 both need to send payments to the same merchant_id. Both app1 and app2 have the string "paytm" + < MID > in the url schemes of info.plist.

The problem I am facing is that after a user makes a payment from app1, they get redirected to app2 instead of getting redirected back to app1. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

In the `appInvoke.openPaytm()` function, specify a url scheme. In the info.plist file, use the same string.

Comment: Shouldn't you mention that app1 and app2 need two different URL schemes?